# Working for an EU employer part-time, remotely in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, working, students

As a non-EU student in the Netherlands, I am wondering about working remotely for an employer within EU.

I understand the Dutch restriction on part time hours (max 16 per week) on foreign students and the necessity to get Dutch basic healthcare insurance during part-time employment.

However, I cannot find relevant information about working part-time remotely. I would like to know what my employer and I should do to set up such an arrangement.

How does it work? Does my employer still have to get a work permit (TWV) from NL? What are the things I should take care of in case of such an arrangement?